# How can I add filters to VertexAI queries using langchain?

Tags: python, langchain, retrieval-augmented-generation, vertex-ai-search

I have uploaded documents with metadata to VertexAI Search and Conversation and I am using langchain to build a RAG model based on the documents I uploaded. I would like to add filters on the documents used to generate the answer based on the metadata I uploaded.

The metadata is in this format:

```
{"id": 1,
 "structData": {"id": "2743", 
                "tags": "Operation",
                "language": "English"
                },
 "content": {"mimeType": "text/plain", "uri": #link to gcs location of the file}}
```

For example, I would like to get an answer only based on documents that have "English" as "language".

I use this code to get the answer to my query using langchain:

```
import vertexai
from langchain.llms import VertexAI
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.retrievers import GoogleVertexAISearchRetriever

vertexai.init(project=PROJECT_ID, location=REGION)
llm = VertexAI(model_name=MODEL)

retriever = GoogleVertexAISearchRetriever(
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    location_id=DATA_STORE_LOCATION,
    data_store_id=DATA_STORE_ID,
    get_extractive_answers=True,
    max_documents=10,
    max_extractive_segment_count=1,
    max_extractive_answer_count=5
)

search_query = "What are some spices that can help lower blood sugar?"

retrieval_qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever, return_source_documents=True
)

results = retrieval_qa({"query": search_query})
```

I already tried to pass a "filter" argument to the retriever I am using based on [the langchain documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/retrievers/google_vertex_ai_search) but I always run into errors, no matter which syntax I am using.